# Document disappear from collection after insert in replica set

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Inserted document disappears from the collection after some seconds.

This is a really strange behavior I'm facing in a new collection my app needs. Whenever I insert a document in this new collection it disappears after some seconds. I have tested the app in my dev environment, with a standlone MongoDB instance, and it works as expected. When testing in the preproduction environment, with a MongoDB in cluster and a ReplicaSet I'm facing this issue. Inserting documents to other collections works as expected, this one is the only collection where documets devanish.

I have checked oplog collection and I can see that whenever and insert operation ("op": "i") is sended to the replica set, after a few seconds a delete operation ("op": "d") is sended to remove the previous added document.

App does not remove documents from this collection on any place

All inserts in application pass through the same code:

```
function insert (document, collection){
   return    collection.insertOne(document, {w:1});
}
```

I have no idea what can happen

Comment: Is there a TTL index that could be removing the docs?

Comment: Nop. As far as I can see in MongoChef only default (_id) index exists

Comment: Are you opening up a transaction somewhere and then rolling it back?

Comment: I don't even know how to open a transaction on a Mongo Database ;) Nop, the operation is atomic.